# How to add Media Center Pack to Windows 8 Pro?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

I tried to obtain it from the [Add Features](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs) website, but it doesn't seem to work -- I tried two different e-mail addresses from different providers, waited 10 hours and checked my spam folders, but no message arrived.

When I use the "Add features to Windows 8" application, it allows to select the Media Center Pack, but says it will charge me about 10EUR for it. From what I understand, it should be free through January 2013.

Has anyone successfully installed this add-on? Is there another way to obtain it?

Comment: I had no problem adding it, seems like your email provider is to blame, I suggest an entirely differnt provide or simply use @Outlook.com

Comment: I used Gmail and my employer's mail. At least Gmail should've worked...

Comment: I'm still waiting for my code via email. It's been a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patience. I entered my email address yesterday and just received the code this afternoon. You will eventually get an email with the code.

Comment: Just got it, exactly at midnight. Maybe that's the rule?

Comment: Could be. Except I'm located in Arizona, USA, so it's been Oct 26 for a while now.

Comment: No, it's already Oct 27 here.